# Characterization of lower semicontinuous functions by neighbourhoods

Tags: functional-analysis

I tried several times to show the following thing:

Let $f:X\to \mathbb R$ be a lower semicontinuous function. Then, 
$$(\forall \epsilon >0)\ (\forall x\in X)\ (\exists V\in\vartheta(x))\ s.t. (\forall y\in V)(f(y)\geq f(x)-\epsilon), $$
where $X$ is a topological space, and $V$ is a neighborhood of $x$. I used the definition of a l.s.c. function, which says that $(\forall \lambda \in \mathbb R)$ the  set $\{x\in X, f(x)\leq \lambda \}$ is closed, but I got nothing!

Please if you have any idea or hints, it's going to be a great help. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and $x\in X$. Let $S = \{y\in X : f(y) \le f(x) - \epsilon\}$. Since $f$ is l.s.c. on $X$, $S$ is closed in $X$. Set $V = X\setminus S$. Then $V$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ such that for all $y\in V$, $f(y) > f(x) - \epsilon$.